# Python multithreading blocks unexpectedly

Tags: python, multithreading, events

I am developing a Python particle swarm optimizer application which exchanges messages with a Kafka broker. I want to send a message to the broker, where another application (will be JAVA) pick up the message, processes it and returns a result. The python applications needs to wait until the result is available. Currently, the code looks like this:

```
class KafkaConnector(Thread):
  __consumption_thread = None
  __kafka_consumer: KafkaConsumer = None
  __kafka_producer: KafkaProducer = None
  __pso_optimizer: GlobalBestPSO = None
  __device_names: np.array = None

  def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.__kafka_consumer = KafkaConsumer('A_TOPIC', bootstrap_servers=['my.kafka.server:9092'])
    self.__kafka_producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['my.kafka.server:9092'])
    self.__result_received = Event()

  def consume_messages(self):
    assert self.__kafka_consumer is not None
    self.__kafka_consumer.subscribe(['A_TOPIC'])
    assert self.__kafka_consumer.subscription() is not None

    self.__consumption_thread = KafkaListener(self)
    self.__consumption_thread.start()
    print('[INFO] Kafka consumer thread started')

  def stop_listener(self):
    self.__consumption_thread.stop_consumer()
    self.__kafka_consumer.unsubscribe()
    self.__kafka_consumer.close()

  def message_received(self, message: ConsumerRecord):
  '''
  Method switching message content by use case
  '''
    print('[INFO] Received message:', message)
    if ('mode', b'INIT') in message.headers: # INIT comes from device automator
        self.init_pso(message.value) <--- this call works as expected
    elif ('mode', b'RESULT') in message.headers: # RESULT comes from device automator
        print('perform step')
    elif ('mode', b'SET') in message.headers: # SET is sent by PSO
        print('SET received')
        self.__result_received.set()
    else:
        print('unknown command', message.headers)

  def send_message(self, message_content, headers: list):
    self.__kafka_producer.send(topic='A_TOPIC', value=message_content, headers=headers)

  def init_pso(self, json_string: str):

    [...]

    self.__pso_optimizer = GlobalBestPSO(n_particles=10 * parameter_count, dimensions=parameter_count,
                                         options=options, bounds=bounds)

    # start optimization run
    best_cost, best_position = self.__pso_optimizer.optimize(self.objective_function, iters=100)
    print(best_position, best_cost)

  def objective_function(self, new_settings):

    result = np.empty(len(new_settings))

    for i in range(len(new_settings)):
        setting_dict = []
        result[i] = 0

        for j in range(len(self.__device_names)):
            parameter_value = {self.__device_names[j]: new_settings[i][j]}
            setting_dict.append(parameter_value)

        # send new setting values to Kafka / LSA client
        self.__kafka_producer.send('A_TOPIC', value=json.dumps(setting_dict).encode('UTF-8'),
                                   headers=[('mode','SET'.encode('UTF-8'))])
        # wait for result to return
        if self.__result_received.is_set():
            self.__result_received.clear()

        self.__result_received.wait() <--- this wait blocks everything, including KafkaListener::run() without wait(), the code executes as expected
        # append to result array

        #result[i] += new_settings[i][j]

    return result


def get_optimizer(self):
    return self.__pso_optimizer


'''
This is a class supposed to listen in a parallel thread to messages coming from Kafka
'''
class KafkaListener(Thread):
  __stop_event: Event = None
  __caller: KafkaConnector = None

  def __init__(self, caller):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.__caller = caller
    self.setDaemon(True)
    self.__stop_event = Event()

  def run(self):
    while not self.__stop_event.is_set():
        for message in self.__caller.getKafkaConsumer():
            print('[INFO] KafkaListener received:', message)
            self.__caller.message_received(message)
            if self.__stop_event.is_set():
                break

  def stop_consumer(self):
    self.__stop_event.set()
```

Ultimately I want to wait for the result coming via Kafka and then proceed with the next loop

Comment: so.  what blocks? where is the code to setup and run your thread instances? In what point does it block? This question is not really answearable as it is.

Comment: On a side note, this is very little "Pythonic": there is no need to "declare variables" in Python just for declaring them. Also, the resource of `__` prefix for "private attributes" is not really a thing, it just make the code harder to read. Python does not have private attributes for a reason: public attributes will usually work just as well. 

(Although in this case, since you are extending the Thread class, you _might_ have a nameclash; the preferred way to avoid it is: not to inherit "Thread", just create  a "Thread" instance with your worker method as a target.